# Facebook graph API to crawl my 'news feed'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm creating a small app that uses text mining from several different social networks. The Twitter API was really useful and easy to use, but with facebook i'm having some troubles understanding which features i need to use. My goal is to get real time data from my news feed . I came across this page : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/user/feed

but it seems like to only give me data on a user wall and not news feed . 
if you have any information about how to do this, i would be thankful.

Comment: There is no way to get a user's newsfeed.

Comment: Not even my own newsfeed?

Comment: Correct. Not even your own newsfeed.

Comment: is there any alternative you are familiar with by any chance ?

Comment: "No way" means that there is no way.

Comment: there is always a way in this field (;

Comment: There is no way that is allowed by Facebook. So if you don't want your Facebook account banned then there is no way